# Winapi WriteFile function write one byte

Tags: c++, winapi

I trying binary file write one byte, and get fails... How to get to work?

My code:

```
unsigned char b = 0x00; // equal to hex value = 00
/*
 Error: GetLastError()
 ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER
 1784 (0x6F8)
 The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation.
*/
WriteFile(file, ( char *)b, 1, &bytesWritten, NULL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WriteFile definition is

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteFile(
  _In_        HANDLE       hFile,
  _In_        LPCVOID      lpBuffer,
  _In_        DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
  _Out_opt_   LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
  _Inout_opt_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

where **lpBuffer** is a pointer to the buffer containing the data to be written.

To get a pointer to **b** you need an [address of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) operator `&` instead of [C-style cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) to char pointer:

```
WriteFile(file, &b, 1, &bytesWritten, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks for helpful.

Comment: @EminFurkanTürkmen Without the `b` variable you don't have anything to write. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I like this function call: WriteFile(file, "here byte", 1, &bytesWritten, NULL);

Comment: @EminFurkanTürkmen You could use "\x00" string literal for that.

Comment: @w1ck3dg0ph3r: `"\x00"` is just an overly verbose version of `"\0"`. And if it's really just about a single byte with value 0, then `""` will do just fine, as string literals are automatically zero-terminated.